Is AJAX relevant when inserting a new post programmatically?
What I'm already able to achieve :

Inserting a new post with the WordPress function.
Doing it programmatically when some conditions are fulfilled.

The downside of this way of creating new post is that I need the user to reload the page on front-office (in order to start the new post insertion). So, I would like to know if Ajax could be relevant and help the user to create a new post without reloading the page.

the user need to reload the page after having done what ?

Well, for example, after an input : like filling out a basic (first name and last name).

Yeah, to accomplish this without a page reload AJAX would be the right way to do it.
